# Want to print out all result from mysqli_fetch_array but it return first row many times

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a database db1 with a table content 2 fields: table user(userID varchar(1), userName varchar(30)).

I put 2 rows in this table: (01,admin) and (02,user)

I want to print all userName out so I code:

```
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","",db1);
if($conn)
{
    $sql="SELECT userName FROM user";
    $resul=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $mysqli_close($conn);
    foreach($row as $a)
        {
            echo $a;
        }        
 }
```

But the result I get is 
    adminadmin
not
    adminuser
Could you please tell me why, and how can I fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you read the documentation? It clearly says that this just returns one row. http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because [`mysqli_fetch_array`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) returns the first row and that you are looping over the same  `$row` in your `foreach`, you'll only be getting data from that first `$row`.

What you want to do instead is use a while loop which is more suitable in this case:

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","",db1);
if($conn)
{
    $sql="SELECT userName FROM user";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);)
        {
            print_r($row);
        }        
    $mysqli_close($conn);
 }
```

Try this..

Comment: You're only fetching one field, why are you trying to echo two fields?

Comment: And don't call `mysqli_close()` before fetching.