# I want to fetch any specific field from MySql database using PHP 7.1.5 but it is not working

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code written in PHP 7.1.6 and I am using all MySqli versions correctly according to Php.net but still its fetching only the first one of the mentioned field.

```
 <?php

    $mysql_host='localhost';
    $mysql_user= 'root';
    $mysql_password='root';

        $connnect=new mysqli($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_password,'student');

    $query="SELECT * FROM `user_info`";
    if( mysqli_query($connnect,$query))
    {
        echo "Query Executed";
        $query_execute=mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($connnect,$query),MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                echo $query_execute["Name"].'<br>';

    }

    else
        echo "Query Failed";


?>
```

Comment: did you take any tutorial about mysqli? Most good ones would explain that you need to loop and execute mysqli_fetch_array multiple times - it only returns one row at a time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Want to print out all result from mysqli\_fetch\_array but it return first row many times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20695635/want-to-print-out-all-result-from-mysqli-fetch-array-but-it-return-first-row-man)

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Ya i tried it but it is getting into a sort of infinite loop only on the first attribute of that column and after. removing the loop it is showing that attribute for the one time.

Comment: Ok.so will this Object Oriented interface solve this problem ?

Comment: There's a number of problems here. The object-oriented interface doesn't "fix" anything, but it helps avoid a whole bunch of problems in the future due to typos.

Comment: Suggest a solution for this one please

Answer (score 2):

You should execute the query once, then fetch all the rows:

```
$res = $connect->query($query);

while ($row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
  echo $query_execute["Name"].'<br>';
}
```

The object-oriented interface, as used here, is fully compatible with the other style, it's just significantly less verbose.

Comment: This is returning the first attribute only under column for 2times(total number of rows)

Comment: It'll fetch each row in turn, so if the results only have two rows, that's what you get.

Comment: but its only getting the first "Name" for 2times it is not coming to the second name for the 2nd iteration.